# MKVMerge and Batch File

Tags: batch-file, escaping, mkv

I've been using batch files to edit the metadata and tracks for different tv series', and so far it's been going great. However the series I'm currently doing right now has exclamation points in every episode.

The file formats are always going to be in this format: S00E00 - Episode Name

Here is the template I've been using for most shows.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set mkvmerge="C:/Program Files/MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe"
set output_folder="C:\Games-And-Stuff\#Anime\zAnime\_Muxing\[[EPISODE_NAME]]"
for /r %%a in (*.mkv) do (
    set ep=%%~na
    set ep_name=!ep:~9!
    set ep_num=!ep:~4,2!
    call %mkvmerge% -o "%output_folder%\%%~na.mkv" --track-name ^"0:!ep_name!^" --track-name ^"1:[ENG] AAC 5.1^" --track-name ^"2:[JAP] AAC 2.0^" --track-name ^"3:[ENG] Signs and Songs^" --track-name ^"4:[ENG]^" --language 0:und --language 1:eng --language 2:jpn --language 3:eng --language 4:eng --default-track 0:yes --default-track 1:yes --default-track 2:no --default-track 3:yes --default-track 4:no --forced-track 3:yes "%%a" --track-order 0:0,0:1,0:2,0:3,0:4 --title ^"? - Episode !ep_num! - !ep_name!^"
)
```

My problem is coming from using variables in the `call %mkvmerge%` when they have exclamation points. Is there anyway to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setlocal DISabledelayedexpansion
set "mkvmerge=C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe"
set "output_folder=C:\Games-And-Stuff\#Anime\zAnime\_Muxing\[[EPISODE_NAME]]"
for /r %%a in (*.mkv) do (
    set ep=%%~na
    call :merge
)
goto :eof

:merge
set ep_name=%ep:~9%
set ep_num=%ep:~4,2%
call "%mkvmerge%" -o "%output_folder%\%ep%.mkv" --track-name "0:%ep_name%" --track-name "1:[ENG] AAC 5.1" --track-name "2:[JAP] AAC 2.0" --track-name "3:[ENG] Signs and Songs" --track-name "4:[ENG]" --language 0:und --language 1:eng --language 2:jpn --language 3:eng --language 4:eng --default-track 0:yes --default-track 1:yes --default-track 2:no --default-track 3:yes --default-track 4:no --forced-track 3:yes "%ep%" --track-order 0:0,0:1,0:2,0:3,0:4 --title "? - Episode %ep_num% - %ep_name%"
goto :eof
```

(untested for lack of examples)

`delayedexpansion` can be avoided if you use a subroutine. The syntax `SET "var=value"` (where value may be empty) is used to ensure that any stray trailing spaces are NOT included in the value assigned. `set /a` can safely be used "quoteless".

Comment: Thank you for this. This gave me the building blocks I needed. I did have to change a few things with this though. I had to change setting the mkvmerge variable to `set mkvmerge="C:/Program Files/MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe"`. I also had to create a new variable for the file path, which is used in `call %mkvmerge%` to replace the `%ep%`. Also there is an extra exclamation point in `--track-name "0:%ep_name!%"`.

Comment: OK - removed the extra exclamation mark, fixed the incorrect slashes in the `mkvmerge` pathname and added the required quotes in the `call` in the subroutine. I did say 'twas untested :)